# Clickable graphs to go to records, not report

Tags: reporting, dashboard

Is there any way to setup a graph from a report to go to records that you click in the graph and not the report itself?

I tried to follow this (in Salesforce Classic): https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_dashboards_how_control_where_users_go.htm

But I can't find the options that they mention. When I go to Drill Down I can only select different fields, not the "Record Detail Page" option that match my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is not a feature of the reporting engine.